# Render the sitemap at 404 page cs-cart (4.5.x)

Tags: cs-cart

Is there a way to show the sitemap at 404 page in cs-cart(4.5.x)? What I did is copied the sitemap.tpl code inside the 404.tpl, but it just renders empty container without links. I think the sitemap controller should be called somehow to populate the sitemap but I have no idea how to do it. May be u can give me any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to call sitemap controller when the 404 renders I had to hook up fn_control function by using before_dispatch(http://www.cs-cart.com/api#312352) and to copy the sitemap controller code inside that hook function. That's all.